# How to assign a value from a range in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, range, vlookup

I want to assign a value to a list from another list with values. I'm trying to find a in a list where does it belong in a range from another list

I tried .merge but it didn't work, I tried a for loop to go through all the list but I was not able to connect all the pieces.

I have two list and i want to do the 3rd table

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0,1001,2501])
t = pd.Series([1000,2500,4000])
u=pd.Series([6.5,8.5,10])
df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns = ["LRange"])
df["uRange"] =t
df["Cost"]=u
print (df) 

 p=pd.Series([550,1240,2530,230])
dp=pd.DataFrame(p,columns = ["Power"])
print (dp)

         LRange     uRange      Cost
0          0         1000       6.5
1          1001      2500       8.5
2          2501      4000       10


         Power      
1          550          
2          1240         
3          2530         
4          230
```

I want my result to be:

```
             Power      Cost p/kW
    1          550           6.5
    2          1240         8.5
    3          2530         10.0
    4          230           6.5
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] illustrating what you tried. Then explain how the output is different from what you want.

Comment: You're looking for `cut`: `pd.cut(df2['Power'], bins=[0] + df1['upper Range'].tolist(), labels=df1['Cost p/kW'])`

Comment: 2nd @user3483203 , also add `include_lowest=True` in `pd.cut`